# How do you read the Railo documentation?

Tags: coldfusion, railo, cfml

I was reading Ben [Nadel's post about the isnull function](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/2588-The-Elvis-Operator-vs-IsNull-In-ColdFusion-11-Beta.htm) and my initial thought was "wait: there's an isnull function in ColdFusion?  I didn't know that!  I wonder if there's one in Railo?" So I typed:

[railo isnull](https://www.google.com/search?q=railo%20isnull&oq=railo%20isnull&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j69i60l2.2621j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8)

into google and [this was the first link](http://www.getrailo.org/javadoc-4-0/railo/runtime/functions/other/IsNull.html). In fact, a lot of my Railo searches have been to similar pages, so apparently this is something that I'm supposed to be able to read and understand.  Here's my question:

Q: How do you read the Railo documentation?

I'm used to seeing words written out in sentence format like Ben's post. I mean: I can see that a lot of work went into this page, so I should try to squeeze some kind of meaning out of it...  When I see for example:

Methods inherited from class java.lang.Object
equals, getClass, hashCode, notify, notifyAll, toString, wait, wait, wait

Does that mean anything to an applications programmer like myself, or is that a kind of internal documentation? I followed the [link to the actual source code](http://www.getrailo.org/javadoc-4-0/src-html/railo/runtime/functions/other/IsNull.html#line.10), but that's almost too much information.

Maybe I've identified a need.

Comment: That is not the CF documentation for the function. It is the Java API for the `IsNull` class, generated by [javadoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Javadoc). It has a standard format to be sure, but it is written for java developers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You read the [Railo Javadoc API](http://www.getrailo.org/javadoc-4-0/) the same way you read any Javadoc API.

<sub>*(Though as you note this is more internal documentation and most CFML developers wont need to.)*</sub>

If you want [Railo's **CFML documentation** for isNull](http://railodocs.org/isNull), you **visit [railodocs.org/isNull](http://railodocs.org/isNull) instead**.

I don't know why Google isn't capable of finding the correct pages. :/

For the benefit of Google I'll also throw in these other links to the isNull documentation: http://railodocs.org/function/isnull?version=current and http://railodocs.org/index.cfm/function/isnull/version/current - they all display the same content (which may be a factor in why they're not ranked properly), so if someone reminds me later I'll bug Mark about getting the URLs canonicalised.

Answer (score 1):

Railo does have isNull()

- It works on variables that are not strings
- It works on strings

In my experience, Railo 4.2 more or less supports CFML at the same level as ColdFusion 10. It is always useful to test. I agree that as of early 2014, Railo's documentation is lacking a certain clarity.

Comment: Thanks James!  Well, I guess the saying is: find a need and fill it.  Maybe I should start posting railo examples on my personal website!